# Генератор кодов(код Хэмминга java)

Tags: java, алгоритм, кодогенераторы

Поступило задание спрограммировать код Хемминга.

1.Предусмотреть возможность ввода единичного кода для проверки

2.Так и массива кодов из файла.

В этом случае необходимо написать генератор кодов, который также случайным образом создает ошибки.

С первым заданием я справилась.

А вот 2-е вызывает вопросы.

Как можно сгенерировать код, который будет с ошибкой?
Код Хэмминга сам кодирует/раскодирует по заданному алгоритму.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю этот пример вам поможет решить задачу:

```
    import java.util.*;

    class Hamming {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the number of bits for the Hamming data:");
            int n = scan.nextInt();
            int a[] = new int[n];

            for(int i=0 ; i < n ; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter bit no. " + (n-i) + ":");
                a[n-i-1] = scan.nextInt();
            }

            System.out.println("You entered:");
            for(int i=0 ; i < n ; i++) {
                System.out.print(a[n-i-1]);
            }
            System.out.println();

            int b[] = generateCode(a);

            System.out.println("Generated code is:");
            for(int i=0 ; i < b.length ; i++) {
                System.out.print(b[b.length-i-1]);
            }
            System.out.println();

            // Difference in the sizes of original and new array will give us the number of parity bits added.
            System.out.println("Enter position of a bit to alter to check for error detection at the receiver end (0 for no error):");
            int error = scan.nextInt();
            if(error != 0) {
                b[error-1] = (b[error-1]+1)%2;
            }
            System.out.println("Sent code is:");
            for(int i=0 ; i < b.length ; i++) {
                System.out.print(b[b.length-i-1]);
            }
            System.out.println();
            receive(b, b.length - a.length);
        }

        static int[] generateCode(int a[]) {
            // We will return the array 'b'.
            int b[];

            // We find the number of parity bits required:
            int i=0, parity_count=0 ,j=0, k=0;
            while(i < a.length) {
                // 2^(parity bits) must equal the current position
                // Current position is (number of bits traversed + number of parity bits + 1).
                // +1 is needed since array indices start from 0 whereas we need to start from 1.

                if(Math.pow(2,parity_count) == i+parity_count + 1) {
                    parity_count++;
                }
                else {
                    i++;
                }
            }

            // Length of 'b' is length of original data (a) + number of parity bits.
            b = new int[a.length + parity_count];

            // Initialize this array with '2' to indicate an 'unset' value in parity bit locations:

            for(i=1 ; i <= b.length ; i++) {
                if(Math.pow(2, j) == i) {
                // Found a parity bit location.
                // Adjusting with (-1) to account for array indices starting from 0 instead of 1.

                    b[i-1] = 2;
                    j++;
                }
                else {
                    b[k+j] = a[k++];
                }
            }
            for(i=0 ; i < parity_count ; i++) {
                // Setting even parity bits at parity bit locations:

                b[((int) Math.pow(2, i))-1] = getParity(b, i);
            }
            return b;
        }

        static int getParity(int b[], int power) {
            int parity = 0;
            for(int i=0 ; i < b.length ; i++) {
                if(b[i] != 2) {
                    // If 'i' doesn't contain an unset value,
                    // We will save that index value in k, increase it by 1,
                    // Then we convert it into binary:

                    int k = i+1;
                    String s = Integer.toBinaryString(k);

                    //Nw if the bit at the 2^(power) location of the binary value of index is 1
                    //Then we need to check the value stored at that location.
                    //Checking if that value is 1 or 0, we will calculate the parity value.

                    int x = ((Integer.parseInt(s))/((int) Math.pow(10, power)))%10;
                    if(x == 1) {
                        if(b[i] == 1) {
                            parity = (parity+1)%2;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return parity;
        }

        static void receive(int a[], int parity_count) {
            // This is the receiver code. It receives a Hamming code in array 'a'.
            // We also require the number of parity bits added to the original data.
            // Now it must detect the error and correct it, if any.

            int power;
            // We shall use the value stored in 'power' to find the correct bits to check for parity.

            int parity[] = new int[parity_count];
            // 'parity' array will store the values of the parity checks.

            String syndrome = new String();
            // 'syndrome' string will be used to store the integer value of error location.

            for(power=0 ; power < parity_count ; power++) {
            // We need to check the parities, the same no of times as the no of parity bits added.

                for(int i=0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
                    // Extracting the bit from 2^(power):

                    int k = i+1;
                    String s = Integer.toBinaryString(k);
                    int bit = ((Integer.parseInt(s))/((int) Math.pow(10, power)))%10;
                    if(bit == 1) {
                        if(a[i] == 1) {
                            parity[power] = (parity[power]+1)%2;
                        }
                    }
                }
                syndrome = parity[power] + syndrome;
            }
            // This gives us the parity check equation values.
            // Using these values, we will now check if there is a single bit error and then correct it.

            int error_location = Integer.parseInt(syndrome, 2);
            if(error_location != 0) {
                System.out.println("Error is at location " + error_location + ".");
                a[error_location-1] = (a[error_location-1]+1)%2;
                System.out.println("Corrected code is:");
                for(int i=0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
                    System.out.print(a[a.length-i-1]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("There is no error in the received data.");
            }

            // Finally, we shall extract the original data from the received (and corrected) code:
            System.out.println("Original data sent was:");
            power = parity_count-1;
            for(int i=a.length ; i > 0 ; i--) {
                if(Math.pow(2, power) != i) {
                    System.out.print(a[i-1]);
                }
                else {
                    power--;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }


    Output:
    Enter the number of bits for the Hamming data:
    7
    Enter bit no. 7:
    1
    Enter bit no. 6:
    0
    Enter bit no. 5:
    1
    Enter bit no. 4:
    0
    Enter bit no. 3:
    1
    Enter bit no. 2:
    0
    Enter bit no. 1:
    1
    You entered:
    1010101
    Generated code is:
    10100101111
    Enter position of a bit to alter to check for error detection at the receiver end (0 for no error):
    5
    Sent code is:
    10100111111
    Error is at location 5.
    Corrected code is:
    10100101111
    Original data sent was:
    1010101
```